# Format google search queries for bing

Tags: regex, search-engine, indentation, google-search, bing

It is known that google doesn't care about parentheses in our search queries. there is no way of changing the order of operators. But Bing on the oher hand is more flexible.

So I've been trying using PHP to make my queries (initially made for google) work on Bing and since the precedence between OR and AND are not the same in the two search engines, I had to add parentheses for Bing:

```
"maison de retraite" france OR francaise OR francais (on Google)
```

Whould be

```
"maison de retraite" (france OR francaise OR francais) (on Bing)
```

So basically, the rules are:

- Open a parentheses.
- Find `"` ? it's an expression so don't do anything until you find an other `"`
- Once the second `"` is found look for the character right after, if it's not an `OR` or and `|` close the parentheses.

So I'm thinking of a way to do it, regExp ? it's not my cup of tea, explode the whole string and loop over it with a lot of conditions ? use some strpos, substr.. ?

What do you think would be suitable ?

Comment: Your example (for Bing) seem to not follow your rules if I read Left To Right is it that anything (single word or multiple word? that is not an expression in quotes) separated by OR or | need to be inside parenthesis. Is it?

Comment: I must have missed my explanation, the rule is simple though: after a space, if the character is not 'OR' or '|' then insert ')'

Im trying to ind a regex to help me do that @sudimail

Answer (score 1):

Try: `(".+?") (.+?) (\(on ).+?(\))` for match and `$1 ($2) $3Bing$4` for replacement.

Works on http://www.phpliveregex.com/